# Get Between Values in string PHP 5.5

Tags: php, string

So I had this function to get between 2 values in a string

```
function get_string_between2($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
```

Then, in order to get support for a newer feature, I upgraded to 5.5.  Now my function doesn't work.  Are there any other ways to do this that are confirmed to work in this new version?

Comment: I almost have a feeling this is a one liner. What exactly it is supposed to do? any example input and output?

Comment: Neither function (strpos, substr) have had any changes in 5.5. Are you sure it isn't other code that is feeding your function that is the actual problem - perhaps some other 5.5 change has caused issues?

Comment: @user1685192: Can you give any example input and output??

Comment: So i've used it many times sometimes with just plain string, sometimes XML sometimes SQL results but one example would be input: '"Alpine":"closed",' parameters start:'"Alpine":"' end:'",' output: 'closed'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test the result of `strpos` for Boolean `FALSE` before proceeding in your code; testing `$ini == 0` is not sufficient.

See the big warning here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php